# Find the number of way in which the letters of the word 'EXTENSION' can be arranged in a straight line so that no two vowels are next to each other?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Find the number of way in which the letters of the word 'EXTENSION' can be arranged in a straight line so that no two vowels are next to each other?

This is how i did it:

_X_T_N_S_N_

'_' symbols indicate where the vowels could possibly go

$${_6}C_4 \cdot \dfrac{4!}{2!} \cdot \dfrac{5!}{2!} = 10800$$

However, the answer book says that the answer is 60 so i don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Have you written the exact wordings of the question above ?If yes the book is wrong

Comment: The answer to the question as you have written it with the assumption that all letters be used will indeed be $10800$ and your logic and approach is exactly right and how I would have approached the problem as well.  I see no interpretation of the problem that yields a total of $60$, implying that the answer of $60$ is probably for a neighboring otherwise unrelated question.

Comment: If the consonants also cannot be adjacent to each other and the order of the vowels is fixed, then the answer is $\dfrac{5!}{2!} = 60$.

Comment: Thank you. I think it's fair to say that the answers in the book are wrong or the question is worded imprecisely